# Target parent next div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I´m trying to target a `<div>` which is the next `<li>` of the parent `<div>` of the function `show_projectinfo()`. I've tried `.next()`, `.closest()`, etc... with no luck, any ideas?

The function is that if I click on `a.more_info` then the `li.slider img` is hidden... I don´t know if it is out of scope completely... This is a div that is repeated so I can´t just use the IDs.

markup:

```
    <li class="info">
        <a id="previous-slider"> < </a>
        <span>01/15</span>
        <a id="next-slider" href="javascript:void(0)"> > </a>  
        <a class="more_info" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_projectinfo()">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="slider">
        <img src="img/horizontal.jpg" alt="horizontal" width="624" height="429">
    </li>
```

this is the script:

```
    function show_projectinfo(){
        $(this).closest('.slider img').hide();
        $('.info_content').fadeIn();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are calling the method from `onclick` instead of binding it with jquery.

In the way you use it, the `this` refers to the window and not the element that was clicked.

```
function show_projectinfo(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next().find('img').hide();
    $('.info_content').fadeIn();
}

$(function(){
    $('.more_info').click(show_projectinfo);
});
```

and remove the `onclick` attribute from the html

---

If you ***have*** (*although you shouldn't*) to use the `onclick` attribute then pass it the `this` as an argument

```
function show_projectinfo(element){
    $( element ).parent().next().find('img').hide();
    $('.info_content').fadeIn();
}
```

and

```
<a class="more_info" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show_projectinfo(this)">Info</a>
```

Comment: specify it in which way? sorry... don´t understand that

Comment: @fxg, plalx refers to the `#previous-slider` and `#next-slider` contents. Instead of `<` you should put `&lt;` and for `>` use `&gt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parent().next() // parent() should be the <li> then next() will get your next <li>
```

Comment: Then there's a further problem, please make a jsFiddle, as this should work when the <a> link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more_info').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().next().find('img').hide();
    $('.info_content').fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.closest` use `.parent` and `.next`, then select the img with `.find`.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3VuhJ/):

```
$("a.more_info").bind("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("li").next("li.slider").find("img").hide();
    $('.info_content').fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li').click( function (){
       var nextLi = $(this).closest('div').next().children('li:first-child').attr('id');
    console.log(nextLi);    
});
```

Considering below markup:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <li id='1'>1</li>
    <li id='2'>2</li>
    <li id='3'>3</li>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
    <li id='4'>4</li>
    <li id='5'>5</li>
    <li id='6'>6</li>
</div>
```

You can see my live [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/puQ8b/) for more details.